# Fix a 2D array made with windows 7 work on windows 10 C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am in programming 2/3 in school and we are writing a 2d RPG game and we came into an issue with the array. Our computer at school are currently running windows 7 and the array works great. when the array is used on a windows 10 computer it populates everything in the wrong place. My teacher is not sure how to fix it and I would like to know so I can get mine working before they upgrade all the computers in the lab to windows 10.

Here is the main.cpp file:
(Don't worry about anything but the array please even if my code looks cancerous)
Also for the array I noticed when I looked at it, looks like i hit enter in the middle of the array but they are all on one line. Also if you know how to copy lines of code on here could you please tell me how to do that too. Thank you for the help in advance.

[Int Main of the file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bfimrj2a2et4r8h/Main.cpp.txt?dl=0)

```
int main()
{
titleScreen();
char choice;
textcolor(WHITE);
cout<<"Would you like to see the directions: ";
cin>>choice;
choice = toupper(choice);
switch (choice)
{
    case 'Y':
        rules();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
textcolor(WHITE);

char map[row][col]={{'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#',' ','#','#','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ','#','#',' ','#',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#','#',' ',' ','#','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ','#','#','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ','#','#',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ','#','#',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ','#','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ','#','#',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ','#','#',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#','S','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#','#','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ','#','#','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ','#','#','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ','#','#',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#','#','#','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ','#',' ','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ','#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'}};
char move, ans;
int newR, newC, select;
CharType hero;
//setup(hero, map);
newR = hero.hRow;
newC = hero.hCol;
do
{
    clrscr();
    gotoxy(10,10);
    cout<<"(1) New Game";
    gotoxy(10,12);
    cout<<"(2) Load Game";
    gotoxy(10,14);
    cin>>select;
}while(select !=1 && select !=2);
if(select == 1)
    newGame(hero, map);
else
    loadGame(hero,map);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  genNewMonster(map);
displayMap(map);


while(hero.alive)
{
   cputsxy(messCol,messRow,"Use WASD to move");
   move = getch();
   getNewLoc(move, newR, newC,  map, hero);
   displayStats(hero);
   if (isValid(newR, newC, map) )
   {
      makeMove(newR, newC, hero, map);

   }
   else if (map[newR][newC] == 'M')
   {
       cputsxy(messCol,messRow,"                 ");
       cputsxy(messCol,messRow,"Fight (Y/N)?");
       ans = getch();
       if (toupper(ans) == 'Y')
       {
            CharType monster;
            makeMonster("Giant Spider", newR, newC, 110, map, monster);

            clrscr();
            fight(hero, monster);

            makeMove(newR, newC, hero, map);
            clrscr();

            displayMap(map);
            displayStats(hero);
       }
       else
       {
            //we will not fight
       }

   }
   else
   {
        newR = hero.hRow;
        newC = hero.hCol;
   }




}
char ch = getch();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

Comment: I added the code, sorry I didn't get it to work before. Also its only the int main section. I am also trying to do this to benefit the class on my own time. If it was homework I would figure it out myself. I don't know arrays yet and I need a quick fix.

Comment: I know c++ except for this, this all works on windows 7, I need help with making it windows 10 compatible. I don't know arrays yet

Comment: Not related with your question but, with array of `char` you don't have to separate each element of the array, you can simply write `"########"` instead of `'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'` for instance.

Comment: Is that new with windows 10? My programming teacher wrote the array for us and was going to show us how to use it latewr

Comment: It has nothing to do with the system you are using.

Comment: They way we have it, I run it on windows 10 it looks the way it should, I run it on windows 10 and everything is messed up

Comment: @Koby `gotoxy`, `clrscr`, `textcolor`?  Are you using the ancient, outdated, but unfortunately forced on students, **Turbo C++ compiler**?  This compiler is over 20 years old, so using functions like the ones mentioned -- do they work in Windows 10?  I wouldn't be surprised if they do not.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie They are conio, we are using codeblocks, GNU GCC Compiler.

Comment: @Koby When did gcc have these functions?  Those functions you're calling are Borland / Turbo C++ functions, and are not standard C++ functions.

Comment: @Havenard Here is a screenshot of what the map looks like with windows 10: https://gyazo.com/024751aae74436958bed6f1a7ad65257
Windows 7 it runs like it should.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My teacher added the conio library into code blocks for us

Comment: _"My teacher is not sure how to fix it"_ - That in itself is a pretty significant problem. It's up to your instructor to provide a solid working environment that allows you to learn and advance through the curriculum. If they are unable to do that I have to question why and how they attained their position.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious True lol shes been coding since computer first came out. Well she is fighting against windows 10 but the tech group for the schools are forcing it. She does not want it therefor we don't either because she does not know it fully yet due to it being somewhat new to her.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The program work perfect on windows 7, on windows 10 as the screenshot above shows however it does not work. Conio and everything else does but not the map.

Comment: *My teacher added the conio library into code blocks for us* -- Probably all the teacher did is have code blocks invoke the Turbo C++ compiler to compile the code.  To move the cursor around requires much more than adding some header files -- you need the support libraries for it, and the only libraries that I know of that actually did this were ones produced by compilers back in the 1990's, namely Borland.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I showed you what compiler I'm using GNU GCC Compiler, the default one that comes with code Blocks. The cursor does not move. WASD moves a character on the screen. I have the rest of the code I only pasted the int Main() portion that contains my issue, the array.

Comment: @Koby Sorry, but what you're showing doesn't seem possible if you're saying you're using gcc.  You have an issue with output, and you're using non-standard, and up to this point, unknown functions to do the output.  So how are we to help you if you have this weird setup?  I still stand that this is Turbo C++, or Codeblocks IDE using the Turbo C++ / Borland compiler unless I am proven wrong by seeing the actual command-line that you claim is gcc.

Comment: Windows 10 has introduced significant update to how console windows work. For one, their width can finally be resized, and is not locked to 80 columns, like it was all the way up to and including Windows 8! It is possible that as a side effect of that, whatever made ancient and unsupported conio work before, has broke. I find it unlikely that anyone will bother fixing it.

Comment: @void_ptr - Which mimics my first comment -- *so using functions like the ones mentioned -- do they work in Windows 10?* -- The way that screen size was determined way back a generation ago in "conio" (AFAIK) were low-level BIOS or interrupt calls to get the current screen size.  That method of getting the screen size probably will now not work anymore due to Windows 10 console size being changeable.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem I just needed to add this code and it resizes the window for the program!
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/1481/

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Conio was not the issue, it looks like I just needed to add something that makes the window get set for the program it it works good.

Comment: And that *something* is the [Windows Console API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx).  It isn't "conio", and basically the only way to move the cursor, change color, etc.

Comment: It looks like your program trusts the console has 80 columns width. You never challenge that, and just dump the map hoping that the line breaking will happen automatically. It happens that in most Windows, 80 is the default width for Command Prompt, but it doesn't mean this can't be changed. Windows 10 apparently uses a bigger limit by default, that's what you are getting confused with.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code and it work if the array was an older one:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/1481/

Comment: You're really not going to give any explanation? What the issue is, what that software is, what it does, how it works... anything?